# Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Missing required module 'FirebaseFirestoreInternalWrapper'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am using Firebase Firestore in my Flutter application. When I run the application through flutter run lib/main.dart it throws the error `Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Missing required module 'FirebaseFirestoreInternalWrapper'` but when I run the app through x-code it builds and runs perfectly. It works perfectly both ways on Android.

I have followed all the steps the run the app using the flutter-cli.

1. added `await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);`
2. added `import Firebase` and FirebaseApp.configure() to my appDelegate.

This is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

How do I make ios run through the flutter command, without having to run it through xcode ?